# Script-fu IDE?

Tags: gimp, script-fu

What's the best programming environment for programming in scheme for Gimp 2.6?
Does Guile integrate well with Gimp?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EMACS, of course.  It's the best environment for *everything*.

Seriously, best *how*?   GIMP scheme is Guile, so both EMACS and VIM should do well; Eclipse has a scheme plugin, as I recall; of course there is PLT Scheme/MzScheme etc.

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I'll try http://www.geekware.de/software/emacs/gimp-shell.el as it looks practical

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I do not believe it was answered well.  GIMP does **not** use Guile.  The current GIMP uses TinyScheme and older versions used SIOD.  Your best bet for developing is Emacs + Quack + TinyScheme.  You will have trouble if you try to use Guile to develop scripts because TinyScheme does not provide everything that Guile does.

Comment: Interesting - GIMP doesn't use the official GNU extension language as its extension language?